# Retrieve value of "InitialRotationPreference" programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In Package.appxmanifest file, "InitialRotationPreference" is defined. In C#, how to get its value?

Thanks,

Comment: I tried using XML parsing logic. But no luck as of yet. I was thinking is it possible to retrieve this value at all?

Comment: Please add the code with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To access `Package.appxmanifest` file from code, you can use [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.aspx) class. It doesn't seem to have any properties regarding `InitialRotationPreference`, though.